# webpack: implement zeptojs into the build

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, zepto

I'm trying to add ZeptoJS into my webpack vendor bundle but I keep getting an error stating:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined(…)

I checked the zepto.js sourcecode and it's complaining at this line:

```
table = document.createElement('table')  <-- 'document' is undefined
```

Here's a snippet of my webpack config:

...

```
config.entry.vendor = ['zepto']

config.module.loaders.push({
  test: require.resolve('zepto/dist/zepto.min.js'),
  loader: 'exports?window.$!script'
});

config.plugins.push(new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'zepto'
}));
```

The vendor.js is loaded on the load EVENT.

Has anyone encounter this issue before and provide suggestions on how I can get this to work? Thank you.

Comment: Where/how are you including zepto in your code? I think the webpack config determines how modules are loaded, but shouldn't actually load modules itself. And the webpack config should not need special settings just for zepto in most cases. (There should be a line in the source file that needs zepto like: `require('zepto')` or `import 'zepto'`)

Comment: zepto gets executed after page load.

Comment: Yeah, but there must be a file that uses zepto. Which file, and how does it say "I need zepto"?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is due to Zepto itself:

> To prevent scope leakage, browserify/webpack wraps modules in a function. `this` becomes the scope of that function, and not `window`

This problem should be fixed when [this PR](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/pull/1244) will be merged

In the meantime, to prevent this issue from happening, you can use [imports-loader](http://npmjs.com/package/imports-loader) :

```
// In your Webpack config
module: {
  rules: [{
    test: require.resolve('zepto'),
    use: {
      loader: 'imports-loader',
      options: 'this=>window',
    },
  }],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using it, any file(s) that use ZeptoJS should have a line that looks like this:

```
// ES6 module syntax
import $ from 'webpack-zepto';

$.zeptoMethod();
```

or this:

```
// ES6 module syntax with direct reference to ZeptoJS file
import 'path/to/zepto.min.js' as $;

$.zeptoMethod();
```

It might also look like:

```
// AMD module syntax
require(['zepto'], function ($) {
    $.zeptoMethod()
});
```

When webpack sees code like the above, it knows it should add zepto.js to the bundle.

Notice webpack.conf.js doesn't need to know anything about ZeptoJS, specifically. ZeptoJS may appear in webpack.conf.js if you want webpack to give it special processing (like load zepto.min.js instead of zepto.js. Or even load jQuery instead of ZeptoJS!)

---

It is also probably possible to use ZeptoJS by including it in a <script> tag in the HTML file and referencing `$` (the global `window.$`). However, if ZepotoJS is used this way there is no way webpack can know ZeptoJS should be included in the bundle.

If for some reason ZeptoJS doesn't support being loaded as a module, it is simple to wrap. (And has already been done: https://github.com/RexMorgan/webpack-zepto)